# Should the display's color match the wall?

Tags: colors, brightness, eye-strain

Since the brightness of your display is supposed to match the 'brightness' (of the wall) behind the display; ***can I stick a large light orange shade of paper behind my LCD display and then use Windows 10 Night Light*** to make my display a light orange shade (as warmer colors are better for the eyes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing two different issues, ambient light and color temperatures.

The light emitted from the monitor should match the ambient light in the room.  Using a bright monitor in a dark room (or the reverse) causes eye strain, as your pupils will be dilating and shrinking due to the differences of light.  By matching the ambient light and the monitor, your pupils will dilate and shrink less often, reducing eye strain.

The color of the light is irrelevant for eye strain.  Blue light, does have an affect on your brain.  Blue light, even in the evening, tricks your brain into thinking its daytime and can keep you from getting sleepy.  This disruption of your diurnal sleep cycle can be problematic, but does not strain your eyes.